# Publish ASP.NET without deploying

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I have a solution that includes an ASP.NET website that I want to build using VSTS.   Currently I just build it with MSBuild but when I copy the files over I get errors - mostly that my `Application_Start` does not fire.

After some digging it seems it might be because my Web.Config has not been "compiled".  Everything I read online says thats because I need to "publish" my website.  The problem is I just want to build the thing and let my release process take care of deployment.

How can I generate a published output (or fire the App_start issue) without having to deploy it *to* somewhere.

I am using Visual Studio Team Services for builds and releases.

Comment: How about building a web-deploy package?

Comment: You can publish it to your local file system, which should give you the output that would then need to be copied to a web server somewhere.

Comment: @Hackerman honestly not sure what that is, I've never had to "publish" an ASP.NET project before. Copying files from a build has always worked in the past ;/

Comment: @David Problem with that is that i'm using a hosted build server agent so the paths are all relative and not "known". From what I've seen you have to specify a folder path within the publish.pubxml - can this be relative?

Comment: Are you using TFS?

Comment: @mason I'm using Visual Studio Team Services

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: We use VS to publish to a temporary folder on the server (often called a "staging" folder). The VS publishing process compiles everything and even lets you customize the web.config file to adjust connection strings and paths and such. Very handy! After you upload and test the staging web site, log in to the server and copy from the staging folder to the live web site's folder. This method works great for us.

Comment: @mason thanks ill try that in a mo, feel free to put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is with TFS, which I am led to believe is functionally the same as VSTS.

Build agents have a working directory with several folders per build:

- a - Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory - This is where build artifacts go. The "Copy and Publish Build Artifacts" build step will automatically copy to this directory
- b - Build.BinariesDirectory - This is where build binaries should go
- s - Build.SourcesDirectory - This is where the source code is pulled down
- TestResults - Common.TestResultsDirectory - where test results are stored.

You can tell MSBuild to copy output to the build binaries directory. The arguments I use creates both a file system deployable (XCopy/Robocopy deployable) output and a [Web Deploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) output. I prefer the file system deployable output.

Create a [Visual Studio Build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/visual-studio-build) step, and use these as your MSBuild arguments. Note some of them may be less applicable to you, you should experiment.

```
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnbuild=True /p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true /p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=false /p:OutDir=$(Build.BinariesDirectory) /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false
```

This puts results at `Build.BinariesDirectory\<project name>\_PublishedWebsites`. From there, create a Copy and Publish Build Artifacts step, with the copy root of `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\<project name>\_PublishedWebsites\<project name>` for file system deploy.

Then later for Release, simply copy the contents of that build artifact to the root of your site directory (clear out anything that's already there each time probably). We use a [Windows Machine File Copy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) step with the Clean Target option.

I see no reason to bother with Web Deploy. File system deployment seems to be [good enough for Stack Overflow](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/05/03/stack-overflow-how-we-do-deployment-2016-edition/#step-8-deploy-website).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did not know what a/b/s folders meant!

Comment: How do I make it only publish one project? I have multiple within my solution but only one that I want to publish at the moment

Comment: @Chris I think you'd need to switch to an MSBuild build step instead, and pass the project name. I don't mind that it builds/publishes all projects, because I control which one ends up in the artifacts via the Copy and Publish Build Artifacts step.

Comment: I'm almost there I am just having trouble getting the published folder into the build artefact.  I am using `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/**` as an argument for what to copy, which maps to `D:\a\1\b/**`.  Checking my build output it seems to do something with that directory lol `D:\a\1\b\[project]\_PublishedWebsites\[project]_Package`

Comment: Do not use **. Use the path I described in my answer. No need to glob.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, your comprehensive answer really helped.  Now its deploying the published website properly and now I'm onto another problem haha ^^